# Using methods of OpenGL with LWJGL

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I am confused on how to use OpenGL together with LWJGL, I plan on using OpenGL 4.4 (or 4.3) and staying away from anything under OpenGL 3.0.

However I came accross my first assignment of a book that needs me to do `glClearBufferfv()`, and I could not find it in `GL44.*`, turns out it is in `GL30.*`.

I would much rather write my code with one static import than to use `GL30.glClearBufferfv(...)` every time, also it forces me to remember exactly in what version what functionality has been introduced.

I know loads of people use LWJGL, so I figured there should be an easier way, how should I be using it?

**edit:** Did not pay enough attention, appereantly there is no `GL30.glClearBufferfv(...)`, but there is the `fi` variant. What one am I supposed to use now?

Comment: there's a method that enables "core" profile - any deprecated functionality will throw exceptions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to understand how OpenGL versioning works to appreciate why `glClearBufferfv (...)` is in the `GL30` namespace.

Each version introduces a new set of ***required*** functionality, and up until version **3.1** the required functionality only grew. With the introduction of 3.1 and the distinction between core/compatibility profiles in 3.2, you may run into removed functions in older namespaces than **3.1**. However, it is literally impossible to build an OpenGL application that ***only*** uses features that were added in OpenGL 4.4 or 4.3.

Most of the commands you need to do anything useful were introduced 10-15 years ago. For instance, `glDrawArrays (...)` was introduced in OpenGL 1.1 and is still critical to building GL 4.4 software. Therefore just to draw a vertex array you have to use something from the `GL11` namespace. You will therefore be borrowing commands and constants from many different namespaces.

Comment: I'm using `Display.create(new PixelFormat(), new ContextAttribs(3, 2).withForwardCompatible(true).withProfileCore(true));` and even `GL11.*` still works, is that correct behaviour? If so, from what *does* it protect me?

Comment: @skiwi: What does what protect you from? LWJGL is separated into different namespaces for each version of GL. The general idea is that you cannot accidentally call a function from a ***newer*** version of OpenGL than your software was written for. You could `import GL11.*` - `GL33.*` for instance and then no functions from OpenGL 4.0+ would show up. It is not designed to work the other way around, like I pointed out many of the functions and constants from GL 1.0 and 1.1 are still absolutely essential to writing a working GL program.

Comment: Is their any way to make searching for methods more bearable, or do I need to remember them by heart? (To which OpenGL version they belong)

Comment: @skiwi: The function names and constants from different versions of GL actually never collide with one another, so you can add a bunch of lines like: `import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*` so you never have to qualify anything. A good code completing IDE will probably make the functions and constants quickly searchable if you do that. I know static imports are usually frowned upon, but the namespaces are absolutely distinct in the case of GL; functions already begin with `gl` and constants already begin with `GL_` - this stuff will never collide with anything non-GL related.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much, now to let Netbeans survive my unused imports when using Refactor Imports :)